# How to create a dynamic html template with template literals and *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I have been working on a toast component which will accept html tags as string. Hence I need to loop through below errorMsgs array and build a list dynamically, but the problem is I have a *ngFor inside that and it's looping the array, but I'm not able to print "msg" in the template.

Please tell me if there is a way to loop through array and build a list and return it as a string.

```
const errorMsgs = ['Not Found', 'Server Error'];

private getMessagesAsHtml(errorMsgs: string[]){
        return `
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let msg for ${errorMsgs}">
                    {{msg}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        `;
    }
```

Comment: What's ${errorMsgs}? Did you try 'let msg of errorMsgs'?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved it using ES6 only.

```
const errorMsgs = ['Not Found', 'Server Error'];

private getMessagesAsHtml(errorMsgs: string[]){
     return `
           <ul>
              ${errorMsgs.map(msg => `
                  <li> ${msg} </li>
                `)}
           </ul>
        `;
     }
```

Comment: How you print this in html, Using innerHtml?

Comment: Like this:-  [innerHtml]="variableName"

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
<li *ngFor="let msg for ${errorMsgs}">
    {{msg}}
</li>
```

You should use it like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let msg of ${errorMsgs}">
    {{msg}}
</li>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Nope, the result is same.